# Стандартный ввод и ввод данных с помощью консоли в языке С

Tags: c, ввод

Задача такова: необходимо ввести данные (два числа типа int и строку). Сделать это необходимо с помощью консоли, но если данные в ней отсутствуют, то значения взять из стандартного потока данных. Как отдельно выполнить ввод данных с консоли и ввод данных из стандартного потока данных я знаю, но с условием отсутствия данных в консоли я запутался:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double x;
    int p1;
    int p2;
    char str1[256];
    char str2[256];


    if (/* непонятное условие */) {
        scanf("%d %d", &p1, &p2);
        scanf("%s", &str1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем там блок `if` вообще? Когда данных нет, функция `scanf` ждет их ввода. А стандартный ввод при отсутствии перенаправления потоков и использования каналов и есть - консоль.

Comment: Наверное Вы имеете ввиду взять из аргументов? так проверьте argc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас написано

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

argc, argv - аргументы командной строки
Они задаются при запуске

```
./a.out blablabla 777
```

При таком вызове у Вас будет

```
argc = 3
argv[0] - a.out - название бинаря
argv[1] - "blablabla" - переданный параметр
argv[2] - "777" - char* (не int)
argv[3] - null
```

Так вот, этот null поможет вам почитать все параметры

```
int i = 0;
while(argv[i]!=NULL) 
{
    printf("\n %s is argv %d ",argv[i],i);
    ++i;
}
```

Теперь Вам осталось только проверить какое значение у Вашего Argc.

Вот Ваш пример если Вы сохраняете 2 строки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

if (argc == 3) {
    int i = 1;

    size_t length = strlen (argv[i]) + 1;
    memcpy(str1, argv[1], length);
    ++i:

    length = strlen (argv[i]) + 1;
    memcpy(str2, argv[1], length);
}
```

А вот если Вам нужно сохранить int, вызов : ./a.out 100

```
#include <stdlib.h>

if (argc > 1) 
{
    char *a;
    long num = strtol(argv[1], &a, 10);
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

Указатель на чар нужен для продолжения извлечения параметров если это Вам нужно, ну и конечно если они там есть, для этого можно проверить его на \n